# Angular Console Extenstions

Tags: angular, npm, nrwl, nrwl-nx, angular-console

How can I add my own schematics available in npm to the list of available extensions in Angular Console?
[image]

Comment: Please look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to google that, but i found only articles that we can install extensions from that list. I tried to add schematics property to package.json in my packed but it's not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all looking for that in the future.
It's impossible.
All available extensions are listed here.
It is not possible to add it by yourself.
https://github.com/nrwl/angular-console/blob/d89c1a8b74be5345a71dd8fd42b4e1ef62ca76d5/server/src/read-extensions.ts#L29